# How to make GitHub history show history of the code I cloned from others

Tags: git

I was working on a project I forked and I implemented the distributed database using gRPC. However, a graduate student in my team rewrote a cleaner working version of the system. So I just cloned and copied her changes to my local directory and pushed to my repo. Then when I checked the history, I found out it doesn't show her committing history. I'm wondering if there is a way to include her work history in my repo as well since she wrote the code and I'm using it. I did give attribution in the readme.

Comment: What does "copied her changes" mean? Exactly what did you do?

Comment: I cloned her changes locally and copied to files to my project.

Comment: Well if you just copied the visible files then of course the history was lost. To preserve the history you would have had to merge the clone into your repo. Basically what you did was not a clone at all; you may have said clone, but you threw the clone away and kept only the files from the tip of the branch.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, copying file will not retain their Git history. You only get the content of the files.

Simplest thing would be to get them to merge her changes into the main branch of the repository you both forked from and pull those changes. For example, if you've both forked a project they should issue a pull request and get it approved. Once her work is in the repository you forked from (ie. "origin") update your fork normally. This ensures the work is reviewed, tested, and approved.

If that's not possible, here's how you'd do it the decentralized way.

---

First, fetch her changes from her repository.

Link to her repository as a ["remote"](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Working-with-Remotes). Her repository has to be accessible via a URL, the same one you'd use to clone it. If not, you can put it on a USB drive and use a directory path. We need to give it a name, I'll call it "grad".

```
git remote add grad <url or directory to their repo>
```

Then fetch their changes. This will not modify any of your work, it will fetch their branches and prefix them all with grad/. Their master becomes grad/master and so on.

```
git fetch grad
```

Let's say her branch is distributed_db, her work will be in grad/distributed_db. At this point you have their work and history. If you don't plan on changing it, you're done. You can reference grad/distributed_db like any other branch.

---

If you do want to make changes, make a local branch with `git branch distributed_db grad/distributed_db`. Git will make a local branch distributed_db and set it to track grad/distributed_db; `git push` and `git pull` will automatically use grad/distributed_db as its remote branch.

What you do with your own changes is up to you. You could try merging them, but since you're working independently on the same part of the project this is likely to result in many conflicts. Or if you have a few specific commits you'd like to add you can pluck them out and place them on top of her work with [`git cherry-pick`](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Distributed-Git-Maintaining-a-Project#_rebase_cherry_pick).

If you want to pick out a few small changes but didn't make small, focused commits which limit their changes... well, now you know to make small, focused commits which limit their changes. There's tools to help extract specific changes from a large commit, but that's another question.